How to serialize and deserialize a Dictionary<string, object?> list with MessagePack and preserve type information
I'm looking for a way to transfer SQL query results over the wire using MessagePack and the message class below.
public class ExecuteDatabaseQueryResponse : IResponseMessage
{
    [Key(0)]
    public Guid RequestId { get; set; }

    [Key(1)]    
    public required List<Dictionary<string, object?>>? Results { get; set; }
}

This generally works, but some values change their type on the receiving side. For example, decimal values become strings, as do DateTime and Guid values.
What would be the right approach here?
I wish to preserve type information only for the Results field.
I tried adding an attribute like:
[MessagePackFormatter(typeof(TypelessFormatter))]

or
[MessagePackFormatter(typeof(DynamicObjectTypeFallbackFormatter))]

but it didn't work.

Constructing a composite resolver with TypelessObjectResolver included seems to be doing the job.
public static MessagePackSerializerOptions Get()
{
    var resolver = CompositeResolver.Create(
        NativeDecimalResolver.Instance,
        NativeGuidResolver.Instance,
        NativeDateTimeResolver.Instance,
        TypelessObjectResolver.Instance,
        StandardResolver.Instance
    );
    return MessagePackSerializerOptions.Standard.WithResolver(resolver);
}

